# restrict div resize on button hover

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a nav bar with buttons using css that I'd like to have a background color on hover WITHOUT the div resizing. I want the buttons to stay in place, just have the background color behind them.

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1C313A;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}

button {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

button:hover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #192C34;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#home">
    <button>
                <i class="fa fa-save fa-lg"></i>
              </button>
  </a>

  <a href="#news"><button>
            <i class="fa fa-upload fa-lg"></i>
          </button></a>

  <a href="#contact">
    <button>
                <i class="fa fa-save fa-lg"></i>
              </button>
  </a>

  <div class="topnav-right">
    <a class="logo" style="pointer-events:none;">TidyBlocks</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Current Output:

[image]

## Desired Output

[image]

Comment: If you don't want them to change size then why do you change the width and height on hover?

Comment: **Links cannot contain buttons and vice versa** - it's invalid HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1C313A;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}

button {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

button:hover {      
  background-color: #192C34;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#home">
    <button>
                <i class="fa fa-save fa-lg"></i>
              </button>
  </a>

  <a href="#news"><button>
            <i class="fa fa-upload fa-lg"></i>
          </button></a>

  <a href="#contact">
    <button>
                <i class="fa fa-save fa-lg"></i>
              </button>
  </a>

  <div class="topnav-right">
    <a class="logo" style="pointer-events:none;">TidyBlocks</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please put height and width in button not hover.
And yes you can't put button element in a tag it's not validated.
Please check your code on https://validator.w3.org/.

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1C313A;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}

button {
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #192C34;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#home">
    <button>
                <i class="fa fa-save fa-lg"></i>
              </button>
  </a>

  <a href="#news"><button>
            <i class="fa fa-upload fa-lg"></i>
          </button></a>

  <a href="#contact">
    <button>
                <i class="fa fa-save fa-lg"></i>
              </button>
  </a>

  <div class="topnav-right">
    <a class="logo" style="pointer-events:none;">TidyBlocks</a>
  </div>
</div>
```